# How to change background color in vim terminal?

Tags: terminal, vim, colors

I am using vim terminal. (`:terminal`)
(Vim terminal is recently added feature of vim, You could see detail with `:help terminal` in recently vim. I am not asking about vim on terminal.)

Background color in terminal window become gray like following picture, But I want to change it to white.

How do I do it?

[image: vim terminal]
Upside pane is terminal window, Downside one is editor window.

My color settings in vimrc:

```
background=light
colorscheme default
t_Co=256
```

Note that I using console vim that installed with homebrew, not gvim

OS: macOS 10.12.6 
Vim 8.0

Comment: In vim generally for some reason, white isn't white. You can check with `hi Normal ctermbg=white ctermfg=black`. [Instead](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Xterm256_color_names_for_console_Vim), use `231` instead of `white`. However, this *doesn't* work for `hi Terminal`. Changing `ctermbg` works in general, but not to `231`. I guess it's just a bug.

Comment: Yep, it's [a bug](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2075).

Answer (score 1):

It may be related to your $TERM env var.
See what $TERM is currently set to:
`echo $TERM;`

I tested this `export TERM=xterm-256color` on a newer version of macos with vim 8.0. and `:terminal` is correctly displaying a white background.